# Building chromium on windows 8.1 using Visual Studio 2013 pro update 3 (or 4).

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, chromium

I have been struggling for 2 weeks now to build chromium following [Build Instructions (windows)](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/build-instructions-windows#TOC-Seeing-strange-errors-using-Git-on-Windows-). My specs are:

- Windows 8.1
- Visual Studio 2013 update 3
- Intel i7 cpu and 16GB RAM

Every time the build failed. I tried many ways, after installing depot_tools after default way failed.

- set DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0
- set GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2013
- set GYP_GENERATORS=msvs-ninja,ninja
- gclient runhooks
- ninja -C out\Debug chrome

One of the error is like: src\gin\function_template.h(152) : error C2059: syntax error : ''

So, I have following questions:
1) Has anyone successfully build chromium on windows 8.1 using visual studio 13 pro update 3?
1.1) If yes,   can you give the detailed instructions on installation sequence to follow if it matters, like (1. visual studio, 2. directx sdk, 3. windows sdk etc. 4. depot_tools 5. fetch chromium 6. gclient sync .... etc)?

1.2) If yes, how can you eliminate those errors like c2059?

Answer (score 3):

It says on the website that only Visual Studio Update 4 is supported.

http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/build-instructions-windows

Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/build-instructions-windows
Chromium is only built on VS 2013 update 4. So it definitely will not work on VS 2013 Update 3.

Does it work with VS Update 5?
=> Answer myself: Yes, it works on VS Update 5.

Comment: How can i answer if I dont have enough reputation?

Comment: @Blastfurnace: I believe it answers the question, even if it's a duplicate answer. It provides official reference to the toolset needed to build Chromium, which clarifies that update 4 is the minimum requirement - hence 3 will not work. It also goes on to add that update 5 works as well, which is in itself some useful information.

Comment: @MarcelN. hi Marcel, at the beginning I just asked a question "Does it work with VS 2013 Update 5?" - that was not really related to the answer, so Blast reminded me to have a answer instead of un-related question. It was my bad. Then I edited my comment with adding "duplicated answer". It's also my bad again. 
Dont' misunderstand Blast, thanks! :)
Thank Blast, too!